# Laplace transform of a polynomial

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials

Your goal is to write a program that will print out the Laplace transform of a polynomial function with integer coefficients \$f(x)\$. The Laplace transform of \$f(x)\$ is defined as \$\int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-sx} dx\$.

The standard input for the polynomial function will be

```
a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+...
```

If the coefficient is zero, that term is omitted. It can be taken in from any standard type of input.

```
This is valid input: 1+x^2-5x^4+20x^5
These aren't: 
0
1+0x
1+x^1
x^0+x
```

You may output from any standard type of output, in any readable order. Trailing newline is permitted.
No using built in evaluation functions.

Examples:

```
Input: 1
Output: 1/s

Input: 3-x
Output: 3/s-1/s^2
```

This is code golf, so the shortest entry in bytes wins.

Comment: Will the polynomial always have integer coefficients?

Comment: @AlexA. Yes. Edited into the question.

Comment: The Laplace transform of `1` is `1/s`, not `-1/s`.

Comment: Also, does the output have to follow the same conventions as the input, i.e., `0/s` and `1/s^1` are not allowed?

Comment: @Dennis It can be any form.

Comment: It's probably obvious, but what exactly does this mean: "evaluation functions"? I'm assuming I can't use any (built-in) `laplace(f(x))`-function, but what about `integral(f(x))`?

Comment: Is `1+2*x` valid input (note the *)

Comment: @Stewie Not valid for both questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## CJam, 57 bytes

```
l_"+-":Pf&sN+\PSerS/.{'^-'x/2We]"11".e|:~~:Em!*"/s^"E)+@}
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l_%22%2B-%22%3APf%26sN%2B%5CPSerS%2F.%7B'%5E-'x%2F2We%5D%2211%22.e%7C%3A~~%3AEm!*%22%2Fs%5E%22E)%2B%40%7D&input=1-x%2Bx%5E2-x%5E3).

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 129 bytes

Regex-based solution:

```perl
sub f{@_[0]<2?1:@_[0]*f(@_[0]-1)}$_=<>;s/(\d*)x\^?(\d*)/f($2?$2:1)*($1?$1:1).'^'.($2?$2+1:2)/eg;s/(?<!\^)(\d+)/$1.'\/s'/eg;print
```

Multiline:

```perl
sub f{@_[0]<2?1:@_[0]*f(@_[0]-1)} # define factorial subroutine
$_=<>; # read input
# do the laplace transform for all non-constant terms, without dividing by s:
s/(\d*)x\^?(\d*)/f($2?$2:1)*($1?$1:1).'^'.($2?$2+1:2)/eg;
s/(?<!\^)(\d+)/$1.'\/s'/eg; # divide non-exponents by s
print
```