# Polynomial Laplace transform

Tags: code-golf, math, polynomials, calculus

<sub>This is a repost of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54455/66833) challenge, intended to revamp it for looser I/O formats and updated rules</sub>

You are to write a program which takes an integer polynomial in \$t\$ as input and outputs the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of this polynomial. Some definitions and properties:

- The Laplace transform of a given function \$f(t)\$ is

$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = F(s) = \int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$$

- The Laplace transform of \$f(t) = t^n, \, n = 0, 1, 2, ...\$ is

$$\mathcal{L}\{t^n\} =  \frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$$

- Laplace transforms distribute over addition:

$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)+g(t)\} = \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} + \mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}$$

- The Laplace transform of a constant multiplied by a function equals the constant multiplied by the transform:

$$\mathcal{L}\{af(t)\} = a\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$$

- An integer polynomial is a polynomial where each term has an integer coefficient, and a non-negative order

An worked example:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{3t^4+2t^2+t-4\} & = \mathcal{L}\{3t^4\}+\mathcal{L}\{2t^2\}+\mathcal{L}\{t\}-\mathcal{L}\{4\} \\
& = 3\mathcal{L}\{t^4\}+2\mathcal{L}\{t^2\}+\mathcal{L}\{t\}-4\mathcal{L}\{1\} \\
& = 3\left(\frac{4!}{s^5}\right)+2\left(\frac{2!}{s^3}\right)+\left(\frac{1!}{s^2}\right)-4\left(\frac{0!}{s}\right) \\
& = \frac{72}{s^5}+\frac{4}{s^3}+\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{4}{s}
\end{align}$$

---

You may take input in a standard representation of a polynomial. Some examples (for \$3x^4+2x^2+x-4\$ as an example) are:

- A list of coefficients. `[-4, 1, 2, 0, 3]` or  `[3, 0, 2, 1, -4]`
- Pairs of coefficients and powers. `[[3, 4], [2, 2], [1, 1], [-4, 0]]` and various different orderings
- A string, using whatever variable you like. `3x^4+2x^2+x-4`

Similarly, as the output will be a polynomial with negative orders, you may output in similar formats, such as (using \$\mathcal{L}\{3x^4+2x^2+x-4\} = \frac{72}{s^5}+\frac4{s^3}+\frac1{s^2}-\frac4s\$):

- A list of coefficients. `[72, 0, 4, 1, -4]` or `[-4, 1, 4, 0, 72]`
- Pairs of coefficients and powers. `[[72, -5], [4, -3], [1, -2], [-4, -1]]` and various different orderings (or the positive versions of the powers)
- A string, using whatever variable you like. `72s^-5+4s^-3+s^-2-4s^-1`

If you have an alternative I/O method you're unsure about, please comment below to ask.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20472/66833). Imaginary brownies for beating my 4-byte Jelly solution

Comment: If we take input as pairs of coefficients and powers, may we have zero coefficient be included as well, like `[[3, 4], [0, 3], [2, 2], [1, 1], [-4, 0]]`? (Allowing this and the powers being in ascending order would save some languages from extracting indices from the list, for better or worse.)

Comment: @xnor This was never intended to be a particularly difficult challenge, so I see no real harm in allowing that

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 25 bytes

```hs
zipWith(*)$scanl(*)1[1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzvyqzIDyzJENDS1OlODkxLwfIMIw21NOL/Z@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCmEK1romOoY6RjoGMc@/9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Pretty straightforward: Generates the list of factorials `[1,1,2,6,...]` with a `scanl`, then does `zipWith(*)` to multiply each element of the input by the corresponding value.

**32 bytes**

```hs
foldr(\(i,x)r->x:map((i+1)*)r)[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDoMwDADAva/w0CEpDoKWCQk@EjJEQFqrCViBAfXxNdx6H7995xgldIOENU5ZDYrw0Nn0R5s8K0VFrR86a@skQQc/YrBVWTqwpsEan1jhy92Sp@VazrTscIcASf5jiP69iRmZTw)

A pretty folding-based solution. Takes inputs as `(exponent, coefficient)` pairs.

Answer (score 6):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), 15 bytes

```
v"*<
0+1"
 1{*}
```

[Try it online!](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoidlwiKjxcbjArMVwiXG4gMXsqfSIsInYiOjEsImkiOiItNCAxIDIgMCAzIn0=)

[image: run]

The two left columns copy `"` 1, 2, 3, … into the top `*`. The value in the top right gets multiplied by that every lap, so we get (starting with an extra 1 = 0!) 1!, 2!, 3!, … copied into the bottom `*`. `{` reads the input, multiplies it with the factorials and outputs them `}`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
J’!×
```

Takes input as list of coefficients.

### Explanation

```
J’!×

J   | Returns an array of elements from 1 to length of input array
 ’  | Subtracts 1 from each
  ! | Factorial each
   ×| Multiply each item in the original array by the created array
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/rUcNMxcPT////H61romOoY6RjoGMcCwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
×∘!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/////D0Rx0zFP@nPWqb8Ki371FX86H1xo/aJj7qmxoc5AwkQzw8g/8bKxgoGCkYKhxab6KQpmCiYAzmGQAA)

Takes the liberal I/O to the extreme: takes the polynomial \$ 3x^4 + 2x^2+x-4 \$ as two arguments, the coefficients on the left and the powers on the right in decreasing order and including zero terms, as in `3 0 2 1 ¯4 f 4 3 2 1 0`. Returns the polynomial as a vector of coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 28 bytes

Input as a list of coefficients

```powershell
$p++;$args|%{$p*$_;$p*=++$i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBRT4MwEH7nV1yaToaA2eYSky0ki3Pq0x7UxAdCFmTnJGMU25JpGL8dS5ENs3gP7d316/d9dxnbIxcfmCQVfc/TSMYs9QxQUVQ0s@0pDflGHHoFzS7paqpOz7ZpXFalYVCJQs5DgQI8mPX1r1mhrzriNMtlndSP7tiBoQMjBwYOXFtHEH5lGElcaxBxxzCEMQzgZkQaTGlYXZ0D9KDQ9TLfvSH3hmUjSLWaA7RDSFdXTVclbbsBcxR5IhXk4jg0zDS2eRd5FKGoxyK/WAIufqqq5SEa@Mpjie4jExKI/6JcQcdbAATOw12yJe6TOMVzBtrvm/dhnOQcTcd8bkyYlt/6CayAdBnAvQ2j7YazPF3PWcI4KIK7kG@fcK0I6uyBI6Z/KM5kJ3Ca8X9zyhsBf9Fu97iIgDi@kDxON8Fksthl8rsrRqBZ6Gkrtm2U1Q8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 10 bytes

```
#2!#&@@@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X9lIUVnNwcFBWe1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoNyrFpdcHJiXl01V3W1sY5JrU61gY4xkDTSMQKShjqGQFLXRMegtpar9j8A)

Input a list of coefficient/power pairs, including zero coefficients, sorted by power, and output a list of corresponding coefficients.

---

The built-in is longer: **23 bytes**

```
LaplaceTransform[#,t,]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yexICcxOTWkKDGvOC2/KDdaWadEJ1btf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDcqxaXXByYl5dNZdxSZyJtlFJnJF2ia4JV@1/AA)

Input a polynomial in terms of `t`, and output one in terms of `Null`.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

```apl
⊢×!∘⍳∘≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x91LTo8XfFRx4xHvZtBZOei/2lAiUe9fY@6mh/1rnnUu@XQeuNHbROBWoKDnIFkiIdn8P80hUPrTXQUDHUUjHQUDHQUjAE)

Uses `⎕IO←0` (0-indexing)

Input as a list of coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>31</s>  29 bytes

I/O: lists of coefficients, from lowest to highest degree.

```javascript
a=>a.map((v,i)=>v*=p=i?p*i:1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAr3hUWSWrU7D1kOiwmIZhKhl@32ZualTtG8qnUj5d99gJV9IPFc4bBIFrk1gwbEWGxYhuc6o5Oh3zxT3f1QzMABuBDcCmQ4j@Aw)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>              // a[] = polynomial coefficients
  a.map((v, i) => // for each coefficient v at position i in a[]:
    v *=          //   multiply v by:
      p =         //     the updated factorial p, which is:
        i ?       //       if i > 0:
          p * i   //         multiplied by i
        :         //       else:
          1       //         initialized to 1
  )               // end of map()
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala 3, <s>52</s> 48 bytes

```scala
p=>p.indices.scanLeft(1)(_*_.+(1))zip p map(_*_)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/cLmqQP3RTNieKga9HVLmeg)

Input and output as a list of integers, from lowest to highest degree.

`p.indices` gives us a range from 0 to `p.size - 1`. Scanning left with multiplication gives the factorial at each index, but since the first element is 0, we need to add 1 (hence `_.+(1)`). Then all the factorials are zipped with the coefficients and multiplied together.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 30 bytes

```
L$`.+
$&$:&*
+`\d+_
$.(*$(_$%'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30clQU@bS0VNxUpNi0s7ISZFO55LRU9DS0UjXkVV/f9/XRMuQy4jLgMuYwA) I/O is a newline-delimited list of coefficients from lowest to highest degree. Explanation:

```
L$`.+
$&$:&*
```

For each coefficient, append a number of underscores equal to its degree.

```
+`\d+_
$.(*$(_$%'
```

Until no underscores remain, multiply each coefficient by the number of following underscores, deleting one in the process.

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), <s>27</s> 23 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!

```c
lambda f:f.laplace(x,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLsY3hyknMTUpJVEizStPLSSzISUxO1ajQqdDk4iooyswr0cjRMNaqiDPRNgKSRtoVuiaamgDb6RBN&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

Takes a function of \$x\$ as input and returns the Laplace transform as a function of \$x\$.

Comment: time to make a golfing language using sagemath

Comment: `f.laplace(x,x)` saves a few bytes.

Comment: @ovs Oh, very nice - thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
p=i=1
while 1:print p*input();p*=i;i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8A209aQqzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0ShQCszr6C0REPTukDLNtM6U9vW8P9/XRMuQy4jLgMuYwA)

Input and output are coefficients, one per line, starting with smallest degree (nearest zero).

Taking in `(coefficient, exponent)` pairs turns out slightly longer.

```python
p=1
while 1:x,i=input();print p*x;p*=i+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoAgDADQ@75ix7IFTj0lfo7gIGyEkX39ek@/0a4ezLQwvE3OinxMkiJdn7GsWW/pA9XNrK7IxmZ7IvTAhAyBMIAnjBAJ0w8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 15 bytes

```
*Z*1,|[\*] 1..*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfK0rLUKcmOkYrVsFQT0/rv7VCcWKlQppGtK6JjqGOkY6BjnGs5n8A)

`[\*] 1..*` is the infinite sequence of factorials starting with `1!`.  An additional `1` (for `0!`) is pasted on to the front, then the whole thing is zipped-with-multiplication (`Z*`) with the sole input sequence `*`.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>34</s> <s>28</s> 25 bytes

```r
(x=scan())*gamma(seq(!x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X6PCtjg5MU9DU1MrPTE3N1GjOLVQQ7FCU/O/romCoYKRgoGC8X8A)

Pretty straightforward.
R lacks a short-named factorial function, but has `gamma`.
Generates sequence along `x` using [trick from @Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/138046/55372).

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
*Vl
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=KlZs&input=Wy00LDEsMiwwLDNd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
ＩＥＡ×ιΠ⊞Ｏυ∨κ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcG7CoUwDADQX@kYIYKvzdHJ4WIHN3EIVbDotSVN/f04eI47iF2gS9WyvwUGSgI/ijDeMQsUaGb/3xN4NJbDlp2AzemY4s4kgSGjmRhONHXx6VWXpeywxgYrbNdVy@d6AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. I/O is a list of coefficients from lowest to highest degree. Explanation:

```
  Ａ             Input array
 Ｅ              Map over elements
    ι           Current element
   ×            Multiplied by
     Π          Product of
        υ       Predefined empty list
      ⊞Ｏ        After pushing
         ∨      Logical Or of
          κ     Current index
           ¹    Literal 1
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εN!*
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FY/Ra3//6N1TXQMdYx0DHSMYwE)

Or alternatively:

```
ā<!*
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKONotb//9G6JjqGOkY6BjrGsQA)

Both take a list of coefficients as input.

**Explanation:**

```python
ε     # Map over each value of the (implicit) input-list
 N    #  Push the 0-based map-index
  !   #  Pop and take it's faculty
   *  #  Multiply it by the current value
      # (after the map, the resulting list is output implicitly)

ā     # Push a list in the range [1,length] based on the (implicit) input-list
 <    # Decrease each by 1 to make the range [0,length)
  !   # Take the faculty of each
   *  # And multiply it to the values at the same positions in the (implicit) input-list
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 10 bytes

A built-in.

```
serlaplace
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7vzi1KCexICcxOfV/QVFmXolGmoaxVkWcibYRkDTSrtA10dT8DwA)

Comment: I‘m not quite sure what the output format is? `3x^4+2x^2+x-4` should output something like `72s^-5+4s^-3+s^-2-4s^-1`

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Input and output use the built-in polynomial type. Internally they are just a list of coefficients.